# VSCode ts-node/register launches old compiled JS file instead of the specified TS file

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, ts-node

I have the following `launch.json` for my TypeScript project in Visual Studio Code:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch task",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register"
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This is used to debug my Azure DevOps pipeline task extension. I have some NPM scripts to build and package the extension which outputs the compiled JavaScript files in the `./bin` folder as per the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I have experienced that after packaging and then making some more code changes, when I run the `Launch task` debug configuration above, it runs the generated `index.js` from the `bin` folder rather than the `src/index.ts`. This causes some weird debugging experience as the TypeScript source doesn't match the JavaScript being debugged. From the debug console:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe -r ts-node/register ...\bin\index.js

If I delete the `bin` folder it launches the expected `index.ts` file:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe -r ts-node/register .\index.ts

Is there some configuration/CLI option to force ts-node to clean/recompile the source to avoid accidentally debugging an old version of the code?

Comment: shapeless plug: try https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx its better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that moving the `program` down in the `args` solves the problem. To quote from [typestrong.org](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/recipes/visual-studio-code/):

> [...] and move the program to the args list (so VS Code doesn't look for outFiles)

So, this configuration works for me at the moment:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch task",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register"
            ],
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ts-node prefers *complied* files by default

Use https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/options/#prefertsexts to prefer TS files

---

Or try using https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx , it "just works" in most cases.
The script for watcher (relaunching on changes) would be `tsx watch` (as you are running index of cwd)
My task configuration is

```
      {
        "name": "backend",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "dev" // script name, basically "yarn <implied>run dev"
        ],
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/server",
        "presentation": {
          "hidden": true,
          "group": "partial",
          "order": 2
        },
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
      },
```

Comment: I'm not sure if/how I can pass the `preferTsExts` option to `ts-node` through the `lanuch.json`. However, I think I may have found a solution [to restructure the arguments](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/recipes/visual-studio-code/), I'll post that as a solution for now.

Comment: And thanks for suggesting `tsx`. I'll keep that in mind if I have too much trouble with `ts-node` - I'm worried the [tsx comparison](https://github.com/privatenumber/ts-runtime-comparison) may be a little biased, so I'll stick with `ts-node` as long as it covers my needs.

Comment: @Xerillio well, it may be a bit biased, but is mostly correct - tsx was made to "just work everywhere on all cases". I recommend trying it (as a global package) so you just know how it works and can switch if you ever want to

Comment: @Xerillio btw almost like your problem fix https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx/issues/18